# efecto hover de chartjs me arruina el codigo

Tags: chart.js

estoy empezando en chartjs, he hice una prueba en la que al cambiar el valor de un select, se cambia el tipo de gráfico, y todo funciona bien, lo malo es que cuando cambio de 'bar' a 'line' por ejemplo, cuando paso el mouse sobre el gráfico de linea se cambia automaticamente a bar, y asi tambien me pasa con el gráfico de 'polarArea'... por favor si me pueden ayudar que no he encontrado respuesta a esto :(

codigo:

```
let select = document.querySelector('#select');

mostrarGrafico('bar');
select.addEventListener('change', ()=>{
   tipo = select.value;
   Chart.type = tipo;
   mostrarGrafico(tipo);
});
function mostrarGrafico(tipo){
    let egresos = document.querySelector('#egresos').getContext('2d');
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 60;
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "'Roboto', 'sans-serif'";
    Chart.defaults.global.animationDuration = 1000;
    Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = false;
    Chart.defaults.global.hover.mode = false;
    let chartEgresos = new Chart(egresos, {
        type: tipo, 
        data: {
            options:{
               animation: {
                   duration: 3000
               }
            },
            animationSteps: 60,
            labels: ['Ingresos', 'Meta'],
            datasets: [{
                // label: 'miPrimeraGrafica',
                data: [300000, 600000],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgb( 79, 247, 112)',
                    'rgb( 79, 201, 247)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgb( 49, 216, 44 )',
                    'rgb(16, 147, 227)'
                ]
            }]
            
        },
        options: { 
            tooltips: {
                enabled: false
            },
            hover: false,
            showTooltips: false,
            responsive :true,
                maintainAspectRatio: true,
            scales: { 
             yAxes: [{ 
              ticks: { 
               beginAtZero: true 
              } 
             }] 
            } 
        } 
    })
}
```

Una parte del efecto hover se la logré quitar con esto:

```
            tooltips: {
                enabled: false
            },
            hover: false,
            showTooltips: false,
```

pero aun asi no se soluciona mi problema :(
por cierto el html es este:

```
<canvas id="egresos" style="height:400px;width: content-box;";></canvas>
    <select id="select">
        <option value="bar">bar</option>
        <option value="line">line</option>
        <option value="polarArea">polarArea</option>
    </select>
```

Y el css:

```
canvas{ 
    width:400px !important; 
    height:400px !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que lo que está pasando es que estás referenciando a una instancia de alguno de los gráficos anteriores, ya que tu función de mostrar gráfico lo que hace es crear gráficos constantemente (y por lo tanto existen las referencias de todos al mismo tiempo), lo mejor sería destruir el gráfico viejo y crear uno nuevo para que no queden referencias del anterior. Para hacer esto defines el gráfico como una variable global y cuando lo creas lo asignas a ella. Cuándo ves un cambio en tu selector destruyes el gráfico viejo y creas uno nuevo con tu función.

Otra opción que se me ocurre es tener tres instancias de cada gráfico por separado y mostrar solo una de ellas dependiendo del selector, esto me parece una mejor idea ya que constantemente estar creando gráficos cada vez que alguien cambia un selector no es un uso eficiente de recursos.

[Esta documentación](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#destroy)  podría serte de ayuda.

```js
let select = document.querySelector('#select');

//Nueva variable para hacer referencia a tu gráfico
let chartEgresos;

mostrarGrafico('bar');
select.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  tipo = select.value;

  //Revisamos si el gráfico existe y si existe lo destruimos

  chartEgresos && chartEgresos.destroy();
  Chart.type = tipo;
  mostrarGrafico(tipo);
});

function mostrarGrafico(tipo) {
  let egresos = document.querySelector('#egresos').getContext('2d');
  Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 60;
  Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "'Roboto', 'sans-serif'";
  Chart.defaults.global.animationDuration = 1000;
  Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = false;
  Chart.defaults.global.hover.mode = false;

  //Asignamos el gráfico nuevo al objeto global
  chartEgresos = new Chart(egresos, {
    type: tipo,
    data: {
      options: {
        animation: {
          duration: 3000
        }
      },
      animationSteps: 60,
      labels: ['Ingresos', 'Meta'],
      datasets: [{
        // label: 'miPrimeraGrafica',
        data: [300000, 600000],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgb( 79, 247, 112)',
          'rgb( 79, 201, 247)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgb( 49, 216, 44 )',
          'rgb(16, 147, 227)'
        ]
      }]

    },
    options: {
      tooltips: {
        enabled: false
      },
      hover: false,
      showTooltips: false,
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: true,
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  })
}
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 400px !important;
  height: 400px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<canvas id="egresos" style="height:400px;width: content-box;" ;></canvas>
<select id="select">
  <option value="bar">bar</option>
  <option value="line">line</option>
  <option value="polarArea">polarArea</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo!!!

Comment: Amigo, ahora me pasa que en el momento que los cambio, se deforman, y no sé porqué, se deforma tanto el gráfico como la letra :( @FranAcuna